# valueNotFound error while parsing Json response in IOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, jsondecoder

I am trying to parse a response using the `JSONDecoder`. If there is value for the corresponding key then it goes well, but if there is null value for a key then it fails to compile with the following error.

> valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Results", intValue: nil),
>   _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "VehicleName", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String
>   value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

```
guard let obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ShipmentsResponse.self, from: json) else {return}
```

here is the Shipment class that i defied

```
class ShipmentResponse : Codable {

    var ItemId: String = ""
    var VehicleName: String  = ""
    var VehicleNumber: String  = ""

    convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        self.init()
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        ItemId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .ItemId)

        do {
            _ = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .VehicleName)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        VehicleName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .VehicleName)
        VehicleNumber = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .VehicleNumber)
    }

}
```

Here is the json

```
{
    "ItemId": "8af66c87-9099-42a7-8a34-39def02160ac",
    "VehicleName": null,
    "VehicleNumber": null
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is very clear that.

> Expected String value but found null instead

Expected value is string but we are getting `null` in the response. So the decoder throws an error if it's going to decode a `null` value to a non-optional type. So, handle it by making the empty string in the parameters.

Model code:

```
class ShipmentResponse : Codable {

    var itemId: String
    var vehicleName: String
    var vehicleNumber: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemId = "ItemId"
        case vehicleName = "VehicleName"
        case vehicleNumber = "VehicleNumber"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.itemId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .itemId) ?? ""
        self.vehicleName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .vehicleName) ?? ""
        self.vehicleNumber = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .vehicleNumber) ?? ""
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(itemId, forKey: .itemId)
        try container.encode(vehicleName, forKey: .vehicleName)
        try container.encode(vehicleNumber, forKey: .vehicleNumber)
    }
}
```

JSON parsing:

```
let data = """
{
    "ItemId": "8af66c87-9099-42a7-8a34-39def02160ac",
    "VehicleName": null,
    "VehicleNumber": null
}
""".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ShipmentResponse.self, from: data)
    print("\(jsonData.itemId) \(jsonData.vehicleNumber)")
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```